# Why can't I use components from separate files with react three fiber?

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I've got a simple component:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { useFrame } from "react-three-fiber";
import { Mesh } from "three";

const Sphere: React.FC = (props) => {

    const mesh = useRef<Mesh>();

    useFrame(() => {
        if (mesh.current) mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.001;
    });

    return (<mesh position={[-5, 0, 0]} ref={mesh} visible>
        <sphereBufferGeometry args={[1, 16, 16]} />
         <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color={'orange'} />
    </mesh>);

}

export default Sphere;
```

And I'm using this inside Canvas like so

```
import React from "react";
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import Sphere from "../Sphere";

import styles from './Render.module.css';

export default class Render extends React.Component {

    render(): JSX.Element {
        return <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <Canvas>
                <ambientLight />
                <pointLight position={[0, 0, 100]} />
                <Sphere />
            </Canvas>
        </div>
    }
}
```

And it throws an error `Error: ⚡️ react-three-fiber hooks can only be used within the Canvas component! https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/blob/master/markdown/api.md#hooks`

But if I move this Sphere inside the same file as where Canvas is, like so:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Mesh } from "three";
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';

import styles from './Render.module.css';

const Sphere: React.FC = (props) => {

    const mesh = useRef<Mesh>();

    useFrame(() => {
        if (mesh.current) mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.001;
    });

    return (<mesh position={[-5, 0, 0]} ref={mesh} visible>
        <sphereBufferGeometry args={[1, 16, 16]} />
         <meshStandardMaterial attach="material" color={'orange'} />
    </mesh>);

}

export default class Render extends React.Component {

    render(): JSX.Element {
        return <div className={styles.wrapper}>
            <Canvas>
                <ambientLight />
                <pointLight position={[0, 0, 100]} />
                <Sphere />
            </Canvas>
        </div>
    }
}
```

It magically works now. I would rather be able to split components to separate files, what I'm doing wrong? It should be working and I've seen examples with react three fiber components in separate files on official examples, but they weren't using typescript, maybe that is an issue?

Comment: It has nothing to do with where you place the components. You are most likely rendering the ``Sphere`` component elsewhere

Comment: But I do not change antyhing with rendering, when I just move the Sphere declaration from separate file to the App component that has Canvas defined it works.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox which reproduces this? It doesn't look like there should be an issue from what you've posted.

Comment: Sorted it out, got messed up packages and as you can see `useFrame` is from `react-three-fiber` but `Canvas` from `@react-three/fiber`. I've cleaned up this mess and now it works. Thanks for being my rubber ducks!